# How can I find out if .html() method returns "" across all browsers when selector is empty?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

How can I find out if `.html()` method returns `""` across all browsers when selector has no children or text?

ex. HTML:

`<div class = "empty"></div>`

ex. jQuery:

`var html = $(".empty").html();`

`html` = `""` in chrome, at least.

Don't see any data on this in docs.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: Better, @Dekel?

Comment: you can check the length of its children?

Comment: @guradio, but if `<div class = "empty">text</div>`, `$(".empty").children().length` is `0`. I'll update the question to clarify what I mean by "empty".

Answer (score 1):

jQuery works on all browsers. That is why it is so amazing!